# Find eigenvalues by inspection

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was given this matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
-1 &  -2& 7 &0 \\ 
1 &2  &3  & 0\\ 
 0&-1 & 2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}
The task was to find the eigenvalues of this matrix without using the characteristic polynomial. What I've managed to do so far is this:
One of the eigenvalues is 6, because, given a vector $$(0,0,0,t)^T; t\neq0$$
it only gets multiplied by 6. This can be seen from the matrix, because the transformation of any vector $$(x,y,z,a)^T$$ will result in a vector $$(4x,-x-2y+7z,x+2y+3z,-y+2z+6a)^T$$ We can see that the $a$ appears only in the last part of the vector, which helps us determine the eigenvalue.

I also know that if I manage to find a second eigenvalue, I will be able to determine the other two easily, knowing that the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the sum of the elements on the diagonal of the original matrix and that the product of the eigenvalues is equal to the determinant of the matrix, which can be easily computed. Knowing this, I will be able to get the other two eigenvalues. I, however, have trouble finding a second eigenvalue in this matrix by pure intuition. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I believe one of the eigenvalues could be the number 4, because it can be seen that a vector with $x$ as it's first part will be transformed into a vector with $4x$ as its first part. Therefore, i can calculate the other eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "inspection with bare eyes method" may work here as follows. We restate the question as follows:

*Which number should we subtract from (each entry in) the diagonal of the given matrix, so that after this we are left with a matrix with zero determinant?*

Obviously, the subtraction of $4$, respectively $6$ does the job. (We get $0$ entries in a row, respectively column.) Thus we have "used the corners", so let us try to use the "middle block" in
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
4  & 0  & 0  &0 \\ 
 * & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{7}  &0 \\ 
 * & \color{blue}{ 2} & \color{blue}{3 } &0\\ 
 0 &  * & * & 6
\end{bmatrix}
\ ,
$$
and only the blue entries are now interesting.
What can we subtract from the diagonal of this blue block?

One observation is that adding $4$ on the (blue) diagonal, we get a (blue) matrix
with same blue columns, so $-4$ is also an eigenvalue.

The other value is $5$. (This can be guessed or we quickly compute the trace or the determinant of the blue block, and "guess" it from the sum or the product with the known $-4$ eigenvalue.)